# What is the best solution to appen a line at the beginning of a String variable in Java?

Tags: java, string, append

I have the following situation.

Into a Java application I have a String variable named *fattura** that contains structured data extracted from an XML...so this **fattura** variable contains text like this:

```
<FatturaElettronicaBody>                                                        
    <DatiGenerali>                                                                  
        <DatiGeneraliDocumento>                                                         
            <TipoDocumento>TD01</TipoDocumento>                                             
            <Divisa>EUR</Divisa>                                                            
            <Data>2015-03-16</Data>                                                         
            <Numero>004600002117</Numero>                                                   
            <ImportoTotaleDocumento>9.57</ImportoTotaleDocumento>                           
        </DatiGeneraliDocumento>                                                        
    </DatiGenerali>
</FatturaElettronicaBody>
```

Now what I need to do is to append at the beginning of the previous XML code the line that identify that this XML section is an XML document itself, this one:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
```

So the final result have to be something like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>   
<FatturaElettronicaBody>                                                        
        <DatiGenerali>                                                                  
            <DatiGeneraliDocumento>                                                         
                <TipoDocumento>TD01</TipoDocumento>                                             
                <Divisa>EUR</Divisa>                                                            
                <Data>2015-03-16</Data>                                                         
                <Numero>004600002117</Numero>                                                   
                <ImportoTotaleDocumento>9.57</ImportoTotaleDocumento>                           
            </DatiGeneraliDocumento>                                                        
        </DatiGenerali>
</FatturaElettronicaBody>
```

So this could be done creating a new String **fatturaXml** variable and first append this line into it:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
```

and finally append the **fattura** variable content.

But exist a smarter solution? I have the **fattura** variable that contains the XML content, can I directly put the  **line before the content of the fattura** variable without passing for a new variable?

Comment: Um, `fattura = "<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\"?>" + fattura;` perhaps?

Comment: @AndreaNobili I noticed you've already answered many questions on Java. I fear if there something we didn't understand from your question.

Comment: We need more context for a useful answer. How long will the strings be? Do you read them from an IO stream? Why do you need the XML declaration? Most XML parsers don't require it. Maybe you can avoid creating a String object.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It you just need to work on the string, there are simple string prepend options:

```
fattura  = "<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\"?>" + fattura ;
```

I guess someone already mentioned that.

But I think StringBuilder is a better way for string manipulation operations as Strings are immutable in Java. So it would help if you're manipulating string more than once, otherwise it might be an overkill.

```
StringBuilder _fatturaBuilder = new StringBuilder(fattura);
_fatturaBuilder.insert(0, "<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\"?>");
```

Comment: _sb.fatturaBuilder should probably be _fatturaBuilder.insert ?

Comment: Yup. Thanks. Picked the line from somewhere else ;)

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you can use a StringBuilder (https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/StringBuilder.html)

Like this:

```
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(fattura);
sb.insert(0, "<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\"?>");
```

Comment: Why not `StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder("<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\"?>");` `sb.append(fattura);` (like `fattura = "<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\"?>" + fattura;` already does internally)?

Comment: Same result, except if the fattura is not comming from a String at the first place (like a file buffer), it will save some memory in the process.

Comment: Ohh that's interesting.

Answer (score 0):

If you have to use this process a lot of times I recommend you use StringBuffer to save memory. If you use:

```
String xml = "<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\"?>" + fattura;
```

You are creating a **new object String**.

On the other hand, if you use:

```
String fattura = "xml text of fattura";
StringBuffer stb_fattura = new StringBuffer("<?xml version=\"1.0\"encoding=\"UTF-8\"?>");
stb_fattura.append(fattura);
```

You are modifying the same object stb_fattura.

Comment: I downvoted this. The two pieces of code are almost equivalent - you're creating several new objects in each case. Also, use StringBuilder, not StringBuffer.

Answer (score 0):

Strings are [by definition](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html) immutable, meaning their content cannot change without a new variable creation. The mutable form is [StringBuilder](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/StringBuilder.html), by definition a mutable sequence of characters.

The best options would be to trace the creation of the "fattura" variable and replace it's lifecycle with a StringBuilder from the start.

As others have noted, the simplest is to express the value as

```
fattura = "<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\"?>" + fattura;
```

But be aware that this is in essence creating a new string, discarding the old, and assigning fattura to the newly created String.

There would be little benefit to create a new StringBuilder at this point in the code unless there is reason to believe the sequence will need to be further modified. That would create even further overhead.

Answer (score 0):

It might be over killing, but I would do it this way:

```
package com.test;

public class XmlDeclaration {

    private String version;
    private String encoding;

    public XmlDeclaration(String version, String encoding) {
        this.version = version;
        this.encoding = encoding;
    }

    public String toString() {
        return "<?xml version=\""+ version +"\" encoding=\" "+ encoding +"\"?>";
    }

    public String append(String xml) {
        return new StringBuilder(this.toString()).append(xml).toString();
    }

    public void main () {
        String xml = "My XML";
        String xmlWithDeclaration = new XmlDeclaration("1.0", "UTF-8").append(xml);
    }
}
```

Comment: That's definitely overkill. Also, using a double for the version is not a good idea. Software version numbers are better represented by strings, or by multiple integers.

Comment: Agreed - changed it to String